# Is there way to implement redirect to bot / channel in Telegram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

I using Python 3.8.2.

Is it possible to somehow implement in the code so that it goes to the desired @ (bot or channel) itself? My further actions are not particularly important. I cannot find information anywhere on how to implement my idea.

Yes, if it was my bot, then I could just insert the TOKEN, but this is not my bot / channel

I have an idea to implement this using Selenium so that it clicks in the browser to the right moment, but maybe there is another way? Yes, this will be related to the Web version, since there are no ideas yet how to implement this in the desktop version.
I will describe the idea in more detail, immediately using the example of Selenium:

There is a code - *it contains steps. One of the steps EITHER go to @, or search chats by element (of course, I have to be logged in in the browser)*

But maybe there is a simpler way, without Selenium, to implement the step of the script going to the bot / channel page in the Telegram?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`telethon`](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) library that can allows you to programmatically interact with Telegram, like: start chat, write to anybody, get chat messages history and so on.

Here are [simple example](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon#doing-stuff) and [full documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html#chats)  about how to use it.

Comment: @YaNeGabar should use comment instead of editing answer. If you don't know how to implement some particular step using these libraries - please specify which one or look for other questions that has answers for you.